# Angular Filter a nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

In one of my table columns I have a ng-repeat that I am trying to filter from an input inside a separate ng-repeat

```
<span ng-repeat="title in book.attrs">
  <input type="checkbox", ng-model="data[$index]"></input>
    <input ng-model="blah.value", ng-show="data[$index]", type="text"></input>
</span>
<input ng-model="search.first_name" type="text"></input>
<input ng-model="search.last_name" type="text"></input>
<tr ng-repeat="stuff in lotsOfStuff | filter:search">
  <td>{{ stuff.first_name }}</td>
  <td>{{ stuff.last_name }}</td>
  <td ng-repeat="title in book.attrs" ng-show="data[$index]">
    <span ng-if="attribute.attribute_title == title.title" ng-repeat="attribute in stuff.attribute_values | filter:blah">
      <span>{{ attribute.value }}</span>
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

When I type into the input I expect the rows to filter according to the `blah.value`, however nothing happens.

I'm curious if the reason it's not filtering is because it's a nested ng-repeat or because the blah filter is somehow conflicting with the search filter above it in the table row.

Comment: Filter should be `blah.value` right?

Comment: No unfortunately I already tried `| filter:blah.value` it doesn't work

Comment: Filter should use ng-model value, so definitely blah.value . Check working example in the Angular Filter help https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to follow the documentation as closely as possible. What I find weird is that I'm using the `search` filter in exactly the same way for the other columns and it works fine

Comment: What does a `stuff`object look like? Why would you use `search` as the filter if `search` isn't defined anywhere, and thus has the value `undefined`? What is the filter supposed to accept?

Comment: In this case `stuff` is rails data I am getting via ngResource. `attribute` is nested data in the `stuff` object. `search` is the arbitrary name I gave the filter. It's prepended to the ng-model of the input so it know's how to match against the `stuff` data. (I've updated my code sample to illustrate)

Comment: Doesn't angular expect you to use ```search```? As it defines it, the documentation make use of search yet it is not define in any controller. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter Otherwise it needs to be a non object type reference or you probably need to declare the object using ```ng-init``` first if there is no controller.

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary. The list should be unfiltered upon page load